# Use an iPhone as cabled webcam / capture camera stream from hdmi out?

Tags: iphone, ios, hdmi, webcam

I am wondering if there is a way to use an iPhone as a **usb** webcam. I saw solutions for wifi and friends but none of them seems to work for a cabled connection.

Alternatively, I know that it is possible to use the HDMI adapter and capture that signal with a capture card but as far as I'm aware this only means the screen resolution. I read some other reports though that depending on the app, the outputted resolution actually changes but couldn't find a source to confirm this.

The 6s camera is able to record in 4k, is it somehow possible to capture the full 4k or is opening the camera app the only way to "grab" what the iPhone is seeing? Could an app be set up to output the full sensor-grabbed stream over HDMI?